Video stream cancelling but video coming through
I'm making a streaming server and app for fun and practice.

Ionic React App
Node JS Express Server HTTP/2
Videos compressed with ffmpeg

This is also my first time using a minIO Bucket, so I am streaming from the bucket using my minioClient.
The client is just a html page using 
The video streams to the app happily. If a bit slowly (if anyone knows how to speed it up that would be appreciated as well).
The weird thing is my server logs keep registering that my user disconnected early, after it logs that the stream finished sending. It doesn't seem to cause any issues as far as I can tell but I don't like having the errors in my logs.
0|capp_s | GET /videos/get-video-stream?bucket=app&folder=videos%2Freview&videoName=cat_video6.mp4 206 3.032 ms - 18595858
0|app_s | Video stream finished sending
0|app_s | Client disconnected early.

The tunnel connecting the server and client is also logging and error
2024-10-25T12:35:42Z ERR Request failed error="stream 61 canceled by remote with error code 0" connIndex=0 dest=https://api.test-app.app/videos/get-video-stream?bucket=catapp&folder=videos%2Fcotd&videoName=cat_video4.mp4 event=0 ip=198.41.200.33 type=http

Here is my server code
export const getVideoStreamHelper = async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader(
    'Content-Security-Policy',
    "media-src 'self' *; default-src 'self';"
  );
  res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy', 'cross-origin');
  res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy', 'same-origin-allow-popups');
  res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'DENY'); // Prevent clickjacking
  res.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff'); // Prevent MIME type sniffing
  res.setHeader(
    'Strict-Transport-Security',
    'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
  ); // Enforce HTTPS
  res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');

  const { bucket, folder, videoName } = req.query;

  try {
    // Ensure there is a range request
    const range = req.headers.range;
    if (!range) {
      return res.status(400).send('Requires Range header');
    }

    // Construct the full video path in MinIO
    const objectName = `${folder}/${videoName}`;

    const CHUNK_SIZE = (1024 * 1024) * 1; // 1MB per chunk

    const stat = await minioClient.statObject(bucket, objectName);
    if (!stat) {
      return res.status(400).send('Requires stat header');
    }

    const videoSize = stat.size;

    // Correctly parse the range header
    const rangeMatch = range.match(/bytes=(\d+)-(\d*)/);

    const start = rangeMatch ? parseInt(rangeMatch[1], 10) : 0;
    const end =
      rangeMatch && rangeMatch[2]
        ? parseInt(rangeMatch[2], 10)
        : Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, videoSize - 1);


    // Create response headers
    const contentLength = end - start + 1;

    const headers = {
      'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
      'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
      'Content-Length': contentLength,
      'Content-Type': stat.metaData['content-type'] || 'video/mp4',
      'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=31536000', // Cache for one year
      'Last-Modified': stat.lastModified, // Include last modified date
    };

    // Send headers for partial content
    res.writeHead(206, headers);

    // Stream the video chunk from MinIO
    const videoStream = await minioClient.getPartialObject(
      bucket,
      objectName,
      start,
      contentLength
    );

    // Listen for the 'close' event to handle early client disconnection
    res.on('close', () => {
      console.log('Client disconnected early.');
      videoStream.destroy(); // Clean up the stream if the client disconnects
    });

    // Pipe the stream to the response
    videoStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
    });

    videoStream
      .pipe(res)
      .on('finish', () => {
        console.log('Video stream finished sending');
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('Stream error:', err);
        if (!res.headersSent) {
          res.status(500).send('Error streaming video');
        }
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching video stream:', err);
    if (!res.headersSent) {
      res.status(500).send('Error streaming video');
    }
  }
};

There is a huge chance all of this code is just badly cobbled together.
I would really appreciate any advice to improve it as well as fix my issue.
I have been testing various chunk sizes to send.
Adding logs to every part, nothing seems to have an error or not connect.
The dev logs on the app show everything connecting fine with code 206.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
